# What other EU countries' population (besides Italy) see China and/or Russia as their best friend(s) and Germany as their worst enemy?

Tags: european-union, international-relations, russian-federation, china, public-opinion

An Euractiv [article](https://www.euractiv.com/section/future-eu/news/will-italys-coronavirus-epidemic-fuel-the-far-right/), points to SWG a poll among Italians that finds China and Russia being considered friendly countries now in Italy while Germany and France are seen as enemies:

[image]

(One can't help but wonder how they square that with the also widely held view that globalization is destroying Italy's economy. I suppose they see globalization more in terms of EU than China.)

I would venture a guess Greece might be in the same boat public-opinion-wise and perhaps Hungary too.

But are there any polls in other EU countries finding similarly now that China & Russia are friends while the EUro core (Germany, France) are enemies? (I don't expect Eurostat to conduct such polls, these are probably going to be locally conducted.)

Comment: I have trouble believing that they could make a representative poll during times of quarantine and crisis

Comment: @Morfildur: It's not clear what you mean by that. SWG seems a reputable pollster. Wikipedia includes it in their coverage of Italian elections etc. Surely the Italian public opinion is probably clouded by recent events (see the huge changes noted in parentheses; China +42% compared to last year). But I'm just asking if this wave of public opinion change has been picked up elsewhere in Europe right now. And phones still work in Italy, by the way, which is how polling of this kind is usually conducted.

Comment: @Fizz: One possible difference is that if you're conducting phone or on-line polls, there well could be many people who would respond to them out of sheer boredom (and perhaps make up unrealistic answers), while in normal times they'd either hang up or hit the back key.

Comment: @jamesqf: in order for that to explain the results, all/most the usually busy people (who don't normally answer polls) would have to be "hidden" China fans... This is a bit like the shy Trump/conservative voter theory.